# Merging multiple sorted arrays in C

Tags: c, debugging, sorting, mergesort

Trying to merge 8 pre-sorted arrays. I'm fairly new to C, but this is what I've come up with so far. Needless to say it doesn't work. What I can't figure out is why. I've based it off the C++ mergesort implementation [here](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Merge/Sorted_arrays) and tried to extend it to 8 dimensions and simplify it a bit, but for some reason it tends to give me the elements of the first array, followed by 34, 30 then it repeats 23 until the end. It doesn't even pick up that 21 is the smallest value on the first iteration.

```
int test1[5] = {23, 24, 25, 33, 51};
int test2[5] = {21, 34, 44, 50, 62};
int test3[5] = {34, 36, 41, 44, 46};
int test4[5] = {30, 31, 32, 35, 40};
int test5[5] = {54, 56, 57, 58, 60};
int test6[5] = {31, 33, 36, 51, 52};
int test7[5] = {44, 46, 76, 78, 79};
int test8[5] = {23, 33, 43, 54, 63};

int output[40];
int t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8;
t1 = 0;
t2 = 0;
t3 = 0;
t4 = 0;
t5 = 0;
t6 = 0;
t7 = 0;
t8 = 0;
int p = 0;
int temp1;
int temp2;

while(p < 40) {
    if (t1 < 5) {
        temp1 = 1;
        temp2 = test1[t1];
    }else if (test2[t2] <= test1[t1] && t2 < 5) {
        temp1 = 2;
        temp2 = test2[t2];
    }else if (test3[t3] <= temp2 && t3 < 5) {
        temp1 = 3;
        temp2 = test3[t3];
    }else if (test4[t4] <= temp2 && t4 < 5) {
        temp1 = 4;
        temp2 = test4[t4];
    }else if (test5[t5] <= temp2 && t5 < 5) {
        temp1 = 5;
        temp2 = test5[t5];
    }else if (test6[t6] <= temp2 && t6 < 5) {
        temp1 = 6;
        temp2 = test6[t6];
    }else if (test7[t7] <= temp2 && t7 < 5) {
        temp1 = 7;
        temp2 = test7[t7];
    }else if (test8[t8] <= temp2 && t8 < 5) {
        temp1 = 8;
        temp2 = test8[t8];
    }
    switch(temp1) {
        case 1:
            output[p] = temp2;
            t1++;
            break;
        case 2:
            output[p] = temp2;
            t2++;
            break;
        case 3:
            output[p] = temp2;
            t3++;
            break;
        case 4:
            output[p] = temp2;
            t4++;
            break;
        case 5:
            output[p] = temp2;
            t5++;
            break;
        case 6:
            output[p] = temp2;
            t6++;
            break;
        case 7:
            output[p] = temp2;
            t7++;
            break;
        case 8:
            output[p] = temp2;
            t8++;
            break;
    }
    printf("%d\n",  output[p]);
    p++;
}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: You should use the debugger or add print statementsto track the flow of your program.

Comment: What is the maximum size of those 8 arrays?

Comment: @nhahtdh -- Why would the size of those arrays matter?

Comment: If they are small, then use whatever simple algorithm. If they are big, on the scale of hundred thousands. then a good algorithm should be used. Anyway, the OP accepted the answer already, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @nhahtdh -- If they're small, just sort the whole mess together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why you get the first 5 elements of the first array:

```
if (t1 < 5) {
        temp1 = 1;
        temp2 = test1[t1];
```

Your code is specifically ensuring the first 5 elements of the first array get selected first. You should be comparing the value of the next element in test1 against the next element in the other arrays, not just blindly picking it. Also, your use of if..then..else if.. else if... is not correct. If you find out that array 2's next element is less than array 1's next element, you still have to examine whether arrays 3, 4 and 5 are less.

Try structuring your code like this

```
int temp1 = -1;
if (t1 < 5) {
    temp1=1;
    temp2=test1[t1];
}
if ((t2 < 5) && ((temp1 < 0) || (test2[t2] < temp2))) {
    temp1=2;
    temp2=test2[t2];
}
if (t3...
```

followed by your existing switch statement.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I can't believe I forgot how to use if else properly ಠ_ಠ.

Answer (score 3):

[hatchet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10774674/1139697) already told you what went wrong, `if ... else if ...` will execute the second block if and only if the second condition is valid *and* the first one wasn't valid.

However, I believe your `switch()` and `if-else` based program is a little bit hard to extend, since you need to change all the fixed fields and values to sort another set of arrays. The following program/function provides the same as yours, but is easier to extend. It uses an additional array `cursor` to save the current position (similar to your `t1`,`t2`,...) ([Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/VZzZL)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int multimerge(
    int * const * const arrays,      // arrays holding the data
    int const * const arraysizes,    // sizes of the arrays in `arrays`
    int number_of_arrays,            // number of arrays
    int * const output               // pointer to output buffer
){
    int i = 0;       // output cursor
    int j = 0;       // index for minimum search
    int min;         // minimum in this iteration
    int minposition; // position of the minimum

    // cursor for the arrays
    int * cursor = calloc(number_of_arrays,sizeof(int));

    if(cursor == NULL)
        return -1;

    while(1){
        min = INT_MAX;
        minposition = -1; // invalid position

        // Go through the current positions and get the minimum
        for(j = 0; j < number_of_arrays; ++j){

            if(cursor[j] < arraysizes[j] &&  // ensure that the cursor is still valid
               arrays[j][cursor[j]] < min){  // the element is smaller
                min = arrays[j][cursor[j]];  // save the minimum ...
                minposition = j;             // ... and its position
            }
        }

        // if there is no minimum, then the position will be invalid

        if(minposition == -1)
            break;

        // update the output and the specific cursor            
        output[i++] = min;
        cursor[minposition]++;
    }
    free(cursor);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int test1[5] = {23, 24, 25, 33, 51};
    int test2[5] = {21, 34, 44, 50, 62};
    int test3[5] = {34, 36, 41, 44, 46};
    int test4[5] = {30, 31, 32, 35, 40};
    int test5[5] = {54, 56, 57, 58, 60};
    int test6[5] = {31, 33, 36, 51, 52};
    int test7[5] = {44, 46, 76, 78, 79};
    int test8[5] = {23, 33, 43, 54, 63};

    int *test[] = {test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8};
    int testsizes[] = {5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5};

    int output[40];

    multimerge(test,testsizes,8,output);

    while(i < 30){
        printf("%i\n",output[i++]);
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I've done in the (distant) past is to sort the first element of each list with a tag sort, select the first one in the sorted list to add to the merged list, then replace the moved item with the next one from its list (which is why you need a tag sort of some flavor, to identify where the replacement should come from) and re-sort.  The sorting of the head elements can be with a bubble sort, since after the initial sort you only need one pass to properly re-order things following removal/replacement.

Comment: Even better: Instead of maintaining a sorted list, use a heap.  Extracting the minimum is O(log n), and so is inserting the next item from the appropriate list (vs. O(n) for a single bubblesort pass).

Comment: In actual practice, for a small N, the heap will be significantly slower.  Remember, speed is not just a function of the `n` or `log n`, but also whatever you're multiplying times that.

Comment: Although insertion sort (which is what bubble-sorting an array with just 1 item out of place is) is very fast for small N, I'd be surprised if it was faster than maintaining a binary heap for any N.  If it is, then for such a small N I think it would almost certainly be faster still to simply leave the array unordered, and scan every element for the minimum each time.  This way, only 1 memory store (instead of O(N)) are done each iteration.  In fact, you might as well do away with the array entirely and just scan the first elements of every pre-sorted input array.

Comment: And of course, everything is fast for small N -- surely what we care about, is performance when N is not small ;-)

Comment: @j_random_hacker -- You are correct that the fastest might be to simply scan the first elements each time.  Though there likely is efficiency to be gained by constructing an array of first elements vs indirecting to the first element on each scan.